# Using a foreach in Java, compared to C#

Tags: c#, java

I am trying to use a foreach to select a Creature from an existing player, the Creature exists in the Creature Vector under `m_creature` however I can't workout the format of the foreach in Java.

I have written the code as I would write it in C# and I was hoping someone could point out the differences that I should apply to have this working in my Java application. I have been using Vectors instead of lists.

```
public List<Creature> SelectCreature(String Name)
    {
        List<Creature> foundCreature = new List<Creature>();

        //For the customer name that equals what has been searched...
        foreach (Creature c in m_creature)
        {
            //
            if (c.CreatureName.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                foundCreature.Add(c);
        }

        return foundCreature;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Have you gone through the Java tutorials? You're much better off learning this kind of stuff, learning Java first before trying to translate from one language to another. What is preventing you from doing this? raw intelligence or energy levels?

Comment: 1. That code won't compile.  2. I use List instead of Vector.  3. If you're searching for a creature by name, why not use a Map instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` command in java uses the same old `for` keyword:

```
public List<Creature> SelectCreature(String Name)
{
    // List is an interface, you must use a specific implementation
    // like ArrayList:
    List<Creature> foundCreature = new ArrayList<Creature>();

    //For the customer name that equals what has been searched...
    for ( Creature c: m_creature)
    {
        //
        if (c.CreatureName.equalsIgnoreCase(Name))
            foundCreature.add(c);
    }

    return foundCreature;
}
```

It would serve you well to consult the Java API, as well as to use an IDE with code completion and object property listing, such as Eclipse.

Also, unlike C#, notice that common practice in Java is to have object methods be lower camel case, so the list method is `add`, and the comparison method is `equals`, as pointed out in the comments.

Useful links:
[String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

[for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

[List API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: `foundCreature.Add(c);` -> `foundCreature.add(c);` and he should definetely read tutorial himself.

Comment: @nikolay Thanks, missed that one. And agreed, OP should do tutorials to learn, but he asked a specific question and that's the purpose of SO, so I answered (and explained other errors for good measure)

Comment: how about `EqualsIgnoreCase` ?

Comment: @nikolay already fixed, thanks though :)

Comment: -1 vote removed with your edit, but still the OP, Springfox, is demonstrating one worst examples of laziness I've seen on this site today. Why he is too lazy to check a tutorial or the api is beyond me.

Comment: `It would serve you well to consult the Java API, as well as to use an IDE with code completion and object property listing, such as Eclipse.` or IntelliJ

Comment: @hovercraft I don't think it was necessarily laziness, since it's much easier to pull up the Java API than it is to ask a question on SO, complete with code sample. I'm chalking it up to being completely lost and not really sure how to find the right resources (strange, but it happens I suppose) so I tried to point him in the right direction

Comment: @2012 I have no problem with IntelliJ, but last I checked it wasn't free. If that has changed, I would love to know

Comment: Just came back to this after having done exactly that, going through the tutorials on docs.oracle, the problem I was having is the ':' in my ` for ( Creature c: m_creature)` was actually a ';' and I couldn't see the problem. Asking for help so early into finding out my problem was the error on my part, it wasn't laziness, perhaps naivety.

Comment: I disagree. He posted C# code only. If he had taken the least bit of effort, he'd at least have stated, "I tried such and such, but got this error...". There's no evidence of any independent effort here to finding something that anyone could find with Google in seconds.

Comment: @nbrooks Try out IntelliJ Community edition - absolutely free. Here is the [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that is bogus.  As you know if you are not an expert in one language, you may not stumble upon the result you desire in Google.  Have some sympathy for the guy.  The switch isn't THAT easy..